# PHP + MySQL - script for search (fulltext)?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I would like to ask for help with this task:
I have a MySQL table with structure like this:

```
author                name        year       description
Bernard Cornwell      Azincourt   2009       Publisher XY, good condition
```

Now I would like to have MySQL Query which returns result (searches the book) on various inputs (like these):

- Cornwell
- Azincourt
- Cornwell Azincourt
- Azincourt Cornwell
- Cornwell Azincourt 2009
- Bernard Cornwell Azincourt
- Azincourt

Do I have to add Fulltext index on every column and then on author, name, year, description?

Comment: Full-text indexes can be created only for VARCHAR, CHAR or TEXT columns

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Select * From TableName WHERE description LIKE "%searchvalue%";
```

This query will return rows where the description contains whatever you put for the search value. The percent signs act as a wild card so it will return any row that has the search value in the description field, even if there is other text in the field. If you want it to be an exact math you could just do this simple query.

```
Select * From TableName WHERE description = "searchvalue";
```

As far as putting it into a PHP script you would just assign the search term to a variable and then use that variable in your query.